# XPath query to find (lookup) another element by ID

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lookup

I'm writing class that parses XML files using XPath queries. The XML might look a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Doc>
    <Name id="aa">Alice</Name>
    <Name id="bb">Bob</Name>
    <Name id="cc">Candice</Name>
    <Person nameid="aa"></Person>
    <Person nameid="bb"></Person>
    <Person nameid="aa"></Person>
</Doc>
```

The desired output is:

```
Alice
Bob
Alice
```

I'm using C# to parse the persons:

```
// these are dynanically defined elsewhere.
const string personXPath = "/Doc/Person";
const string nameXPath = "/Doc/Name[@id=current()/@nameid]"; // <== modify this line

void ParseXDocument(XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (var personElement in doc.XPathSelectElements(personXPath))
    {
        var nameElement = personElement.XPathSelectElement(nameXPath);
        Console.WriteLine(nameElement.Value);
    }
}
```

Is this possible just by modifying the nameXPath variable?
(My software shouldn't "know" the XML structure, the only thing that maps the XML to my own class are the x-paths, which are configurable.)

Another example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLibrary()
{
    string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
        <Writer ID=""writer1""><Name>Shakespeare</Name></Writer>
        <Writer ID=""writer2""><Name>Tolkien</Name></Writer>
        <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer1"" /><Title>Sonnet 18</Title></Book>
        <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
        <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
         </Library>"; 

    var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title"; 
    var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "??? what to put here ???";

    var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

    Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["Sonnet 18"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
}

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> ExtractBooks(string xml, string titleXPath,  string writerXPath)
{
    var library = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    foreach(var book in library.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "Book"))
    {
        var title = book.XPathSelectElement(titleXPath).Value;
        var writer = book.XPathSelectElement(writerXPath).Value;
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(title, writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it impossible to do what you want. You have two calls `XPathSelectElements` thus two contexts. So you need to pass the values around as I showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New answer. Old answer below

Sombody pointed out correctly:

- XPath 2.0 is not supported in .NET, period
- The data model and the query language are separate things.

So I solved it by using a third party XPath 2 library, The [XPath2 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/). This allows for expressions like

```
for $c in . return ../Writer[@ID=$c/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name
```

Note that I needed to use a relative path from book to writer. This does **not** work:

```
# does not work due to the absolute path
for $c in . return /Library/Writer[@ID=$c/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name
```

For future reference: this code works after installing the nuget pacage:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Wmhelp.XPath2;

namespace My.Library
{
    [TestClass]
    class WmhelpTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LibraryTest()
        {
            string xmlFromMessage = @"<Library>
                <Writer ID=""writer1""><Name>Shakespeare</Name></Writer>
                <Writer ID=""writer2""><Name>Tolkien</Name></Writer>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer1"" /><Title>King Lear</Title></Book>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>The Hobbit</Title></Book>
                <Book><WriterRef REFID=""writer2"" /><Title>Lord of the Rings</Title></Book>
            </Library>";

            var titleXPathFromConfigurationFile = "./Title";
            var writerXPathFromConfigurationFile = "for $curr in . return ../Writer[@ID=$curr/WriterRef/@REFID]/Name";

            var library = ExtractBooks(xmlFromMessage, titleXPathFromConfigurationFile, writerXPathFromConfigurationFile).ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.Value);

            Assert.AreEqual("Shakespeare", library["King Lear"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["The Hobbit"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Tolkien", library["Lord of the Rings"]);
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtractBooks(string xml, string titleXPath, string writerXPath)
        {
            var library = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            foreach (var book in library.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name == "Book"))
            {
                var title = book.XPath2SelectElement(titleXPath).Value;
                var writer = book.XPath2SelectElement(writerXPath).Value;
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(title, writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Below my old answer

I used a dirty fix: in my xpath, I replace "current()"  with the actual value. That way the current-function behaves similar to [the xslt-standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current).

```
class MyClass
{

    // these are dynanically defined elsewhere.
    const string personXPath = "/Doc/Person";
    const string nameXPath = "/Doc/Name[@id=current()/@nameid]"; 
    XElement _node;

    void ParseXDocument(XDocument doc)
    {
        foreach (var personElement in doc.XPathSelectElements(personXPath))
        {
            _node = personElement; // my actual code is a bit cleaner
            var nameElement = personElement.XPathSelectElement(PreParse(nameXPath));
            Console.WriteLine(nameElement.Value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pre-evaluates calls to current()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xpath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string PreParse(string xpath)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var part in Tokenize(xpath))
        {
            if (part.Trim().StartsWith("current()"))
            {
                var query = part.Replace("current()", ".");
                sb.Append("'")
                    .Append(EvaluateXPath(query))
                    .Append("'");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(part);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string path)
    {
        var begin = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            if ("[=]".Contains(path[i]))
            {
                yield return path.Substring(begin, i - begin);
                yield return path[i].ToString();
                begin = i + 1;
            }
        }
        yield return path.Substring(begin);
    }

    private string EvaluateXPath(string xpath)
    {
        var result = _node.XPathEvaluate(xpath);
        if (result is IEnumerable)
            foreach (var node in (IEnumerable)result)
                return (node as XElement)?.Value ?? (node as XAttribute).Value;
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to put the value obtained from the first XPath to the second expression.

```
const string personXPath = "/Doc/Person";
const string nameXPath = "/Doc/Name[@id='{0}']";


foreach (var personElement in doc.XPathSelectElements(personXPath))
{
    var nameid = personElement.Attribute("nameid").Value;
    var nameElement = doc.XPathSelectElement(string.Format(nameXPath, nameid));
    Console.WriteLine(nameElement.Value);
}
```